# Return the Link of first result in google search in PHP

Tags: php, google-search

I want to return the first URL of google search result like:
[First Url Result](https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/media-resources/science-in-5/episode-14---covid-19---tests?gclid=Cj0KCQjw6s2IBhCnARIsAP8RfAgqA2mqM1a54Kv8FFvUb1SvQaKLcNeoTL8jf2-UeGXYubvfK2cLEp4aAn5kEALw_wcB)

[image: Google search]

.php code:

```
<?php
        //Check if submit button is clicked or not
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $text = $_POST['text'];
            // echo $text;

            function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
                $ch = curl_init();
            
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            
                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
            
                return $data;
            }
            
            $query =  $text;
            $url = 'http://www.google.co.in/search?q='.urlencode($query).'';
            echo $url;
            $scrape = file_get_contents_curl($url);
            echo $scrape;
?>
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: You didn't say what the outcome of your code above was, but Google doesn't generally like you trying to scrape their search page, you'll probably find it's blocked / obfuscated / unusuable in some way from the cURL request. Use their Search API instead.

Answer (score 3):

By default since using this scraping method only sends an HTTP request and does not run render page as browsers do, google won't load you the page you are looking for and it will show you an agreement page like this.
[image]

You should use the google Search API as mentioned by ADyson in the comment

Another approach which **is not recommended** is that you use `selenium` or any headless browser. Using the headless browser you will still be prompt by agreement but behind it you can scrape the search results.
[image]